# AJAX call data returned from mvc function is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I know this has been asked 1000 times before but I have hit a brick wall with this.^have created a web application that inserts user data and feedback for the user and the code below is basically part of the PhoneGap application. The strange thing is that the code works perfectly in a web browser but not in Phonegap (output iPad via Xcode).

Therefore would someone know why I am getting an undefined error for the following AJAX call, just after the success callback and the alert(data.ResultId). , any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

```
// POST: /Result/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Result result)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        result.ResultDate = DateTime.Now;
        repository.InsertResult(result);
        repository.Save();

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            int ResultId = result.ResultId;

            try
            {   //valid database entry..send back new ResultId
                return Json(new { Success = true, ResultId, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
            }
            catch
            {    // no database entry
                return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "Error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(result);
}
```

Insert QnA

```
function InsertQnA() {
    //hardcoded for testing
    Q1 = 10;
    Q2 = 10;
    Q3 = 10;
    Q4 = 10;
    Q5 = 10;
    Q6 = 10;
    Q7 = 10;
    Q8 = 10;
    Q9 = 10;
    Q10 = 10;
    localStorage.setItem("Total",100);
    localStorage.setItem("CaseStudy", 1);
    localStorage.setItem("UserId",1);
    Attempts = "1";
    ////////////////


    $.ajax({
        url: Domain + '/Result/Create',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: '{"Q1":"' + Q1 + '","Q2":"' + Q2 + '","Q3":"' + Q3 + '","Q4":"' + Q4 + '","Q5":"' + Q5 + '","Q6":"' + Q6 + '","Q7":"' + Q7 + '","Q8":"' + Q8 + '","Q9":"' + Q9 + '","Q10":"' + Q10 + '","Total":"' + localStorage.getItem("Total") + '","CaseStudy":"' + localStorage.getItem("CaseStudy") + '","UserId":"' + localStorage.getItem("UserId") + '","Attempts":"' + QnANumAttempts + '"}',
    //  dataType : "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.ResultId);

            if (data.Success==true) {
            }
            else if (data.Success==false) {
                viewModel.UserId("Your entry has not been saved, please try again.");
            }       
        },
    }).fail(
        function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I just saw that your if statement has no body. Could it be that this is causing the problems?

Comment: if you mean an html body, i have stripped out the code for brevity.

Comment: No I meant code between the two curly brackets like "if(statment){doSomething()}

Comment: Yes I have stripped that out too for brevity, the problem is with the data being returned as it is coming back as undefined i.e alert(data.ResultId) or if i use alert(data.Success), they are both undefined?

Comment: Well this sounds more like a server side problem, since your ajax call get's an answer, otherwise it wouldn't call the success method, but your data isn't set

Comment: Ok but the thing is that the ResultId is being returned when I use ALL web browsers incuding Safari so I am totally confused.

Comment: This is my problem as I created the whole app using, Chrome/ Safari, little did I know that PhoneGap would use its own rendering engine and I would get stuck in a hole.

Comment: Hm, I had the same issues you are having now when I started to develop with cordova and it was always a problem with the sop and using jsonp fixed it usually.

Comment: I understand but if it worked only on jsonp, 99% of my app would not be working so its something else, one thing is that I am using Cordova 2.0, so Im assuming its using an old engine so cannot handle as well as most browsers that get constantly updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was tying to use the same ActionResult to serve an MVC view as well as an htlm5 cordova iOS app. I got round this by copying the ActionResult but changing the return type to a string, note the code looks a bit different in the action, however the original worked fine too. Many thanks to all who posted

```
[HttpPost]
        public string CreateResult(Result result)
        {

            result.ResultDate = DateTime.Now;
            repository.InsertResult(result);
            repository.Save();

            if (result == null)
            {
                // User entity does not exist in db, return 0
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(0);
            }
            else
            {
                // Success return user
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
            }

        }
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
                 url: Domain + '/Result/CreateResult',
                 cache: false,
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 data: '{"Q1":"' + Q1 + '","Q2":"' + Q2 + '","Q3":"' + Q3 + '","Q4":"' + Q4 + '","Q5":"' + Q5 + '","Q6":"' + Q6 + '","Q7":"' + Q7 + '","Q8":"' + Q8 + '","Q9":"' + Q9 + '","Q10":"' + Q10 + '","Total":"' + localStorage.getItem("Total") + '","CaseStudy":"' + localStorage.getItem("CaseStudy") + '","UserId":"' + localStorage.getItem("UserId") + '","Attempts":"' + QnANumAttempts + '"}',
                 success: function (data) {

                 try {

                 if (data != 0) {

                 //result id used for feedback insertion > update result entity
                 localStorage.setItem("ResultId", data.ResultId);

                 viewModel.UserId("You have successfully completed case study " + localStorage.getItem("CaseStudy") + ", please fill out the <a href=evaluation.html target=_self>evaluation.<a/>");

                 //reset locals
                 ResetLocalStorage();

                 //count number of entities for User
                 CountUserEntitiesInResults();

                 }
                 else
                 {
                    viewModel.UserId("Your entry has not been saved, please try again.");
                 }
                 }catch(error) {
                 alert("This is the error which might be: "+error.message);
                 }
                 },
                 }).fail(
                         function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                         console.log(xhr.statusText);
                         console.log(textStatus);
                         console.log(err);
                         });​
```